# Include errorObject in log4j2 exception message

Tags: java, log4j2

When calling logger.error() a 'Throwable' object can be included. The log output can then show the exception's stack trace etc. Is there any customisation pattern that will allow an exceptions fields to be printed?

In this case we are throwing a RestException which includes a 'JsonNode errorObject' field. Can this be added to the log without a code change?

Answer (score 0):

you could use this method to log the exception stack to String

```
public String stackTraceToString(Throwable e) {
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (StackTraceElement element : e.getStackTrace()) {
    sb.append(element.toString());
    sb.append("\n");
}
return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require a code change. Is there a log4j2 logging pattern that can reach into the exception object and pull out fields? Trying to diagnose a problem on-site without having to update the deployed code.